# Memory leak on MySQL slave?

Tags: mysql, replication, innodb, memory, percona

I have a Percona MySQL master-slave server configuration(5.6.20-68.0). The memory usage by MySQL on the slave server is constantly growing.

Now it reached 68G despite the fact that `innodb_buffer_pool_size` was set to 30720M. On the Master server memory is stable. Any idea?

I have checked the connections on both servers. But the results are strange. On the Master DB server there are more connections than on the slave:

#### Master

```
netstat | grep TIME_WAIT | wc -l

148

htop
mysql VIRT 44G RES 34,7G
```

#### Slave

```
netstat | grep TIME_WAIT | wc -l

78

htop
mysql VIRT 174G RES 68G
```